# View RSS feeds in Chrome instead of downloading it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, rss, xml

Before, if I go to a RSS feed (.xml file), Chrome displays it. I could use extensions to format the feed or just view the source directly. However, now, Chrome forces me to view the feed using a RSS reader. How can I view the XML file directly instead of opening it in a RSS reader?

Comment: It looks like there is a bug open against Chrome regarding this:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=140233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Google Chrome aims to be a fast, simple, minimal browser, it has to make some minor sacrifices in order to remain lightweight and speedy. One of these sacrifices is that it, unlike other major browsers, includes no built-in RSS reader.

> Google Chrome aims to be secure, fast, simple and stable. There are extensive differences from its peers in Chrome's minimalistic user interface, which is atypical of modern web browsers. For example, Chrome does not render RSS feeds. One of Chrome's strengths is its application performance and JavaScript processing speed, both of which were independently verified by multiple websites to be the swiftest among the major browsers of its time.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_chrome#Features

Having said that, there are several extensions that can add this capability to Google Chrome. You can easily find them by [searching for "RSS viewer"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rss%20viewer) in the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 8):

Add `view-source:` in the front of your URL.

In example:

```
view-source:http://superuser.com/feeds/question/456411
```

Comment: When I do this, the code lacks syntax highlighting? Is this true for others or the result of some extension I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Feed Intent Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oceapojkdgeophkjdijkpbjifdnfimdh) extension.

Comment: Feed itnent viewer is buggy and seems to be showing me a cached version of the feed instead of the latest xml.  This is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension called [XML Tree](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbammbheopgpmaagmckhpjbfgdfkpadb?hl=en), as well as the Feed Intent Viewer in the previous answer.

There's also a web app (*although I haven't tried it*) that lets you view the XML file directly in Chrome (or any other browser) as well.

> http://xmlviewer.scripting.com/?url=[URL/XML file here]

You might be able to view the source of the XML too if it formats it properly.